# how can i send message from an android device to another android device using Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer?

Tags: android, p2p, wifip2p

I want to create chat application using wifi peer to peer,am already establish communication between devices using [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html) ,but am little bit confused when am trying to transfer data.First time am working with peer communication,Please help me how can i achieve this.is there any sample chat app for reference. Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the "Transferring data" section here => https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: thank you for spare your time,am already checked it,in this link he create folder and copied but i want direct transfer,here am confused

Comment: It would be great if you could post some code here. And where exactly in said code you are facing the problem?

Comment: You can create it with parse https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse or Try this https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter

Comment: You can use https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/android-wifi-direct-tutorial.30409/#post176526 this lib